# Code to Loop Through the COntrols of Userform and Prompt if any field is empty

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform whose image is attached below.
[image]

What i need is when i press the submit button, it should promptv if there is any textbox left empty in the userform.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim intTextBox As Integer
For intTextBox = 1 To 2

If Controls("TextBox" & intTextBox) = "" Then
MsgBox ("TextBox" & intTextBox & "blank. Please enter relevant data!")
Exit For
End If
Next intTextBox

End Sub
```

I am getting error at  **If Controls("TextBox" & intTextBox) = "" Then** as could not find the specified object.

Kindly review and advise.

Comment: check the code in my answer below, and see if it works like you wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find which `TextBox` is left empty, you need to loop through all `Controls` in your user_Form. Then, for each `Control` you need to check if it's type `TextBox` **>>** if it is, then check if it's empty.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ctrl As Control

' loop through all controls in User_Form
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    ' check if "TextBox"
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" Then

        ' if current TextBox is empty
        If ctrl.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox ctrl.Name & "blank. Please enter relevant data!"
            Exit For
        End If

    End If

    ' check if "ComboBox"
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "ComboBox" Then

        ' if current ComboBox is empty
        If ctrl.Value = "" Then
            MsgBox ctrl.Name & "blank. Please enter relevant data!"
            Exit For
        End If

    End If
Next ctrl

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Shai. One more question if i want this loop to include the combobox in the userform and then prompt that this combobox box and textbox is empty. how is that possible...

Comment: @SalmanKhan just add anothe `If` to check if "ComboBox" , OK ?

Comment: @Rado Perfect. Thanks Rado

Comment: @Rado If i want to loop all the controls and if there is only a sinlgle field is empty then it prompt"Please fill in all details" else <code>... how it will be done...

Comment: TextBoxes have a `Value` property that you can use to combine both statements.  When I was test I found that using `TextBox.Text` without the TextBox having focus will throw `Error 2185 You can't reference a property or method for a control unless the control has the focus.`.